# Using JSON HttpMessageConverters with Spring Boot

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm trying to use HTTPMessageConverters to translate JSON input to an object when my API is invoked. However, I'm seeing an error message when I attempt to map my API input to a POJO. Given the error message, I assume the issue is related to the CreateUserRequest class implementation.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated! Please see below:

**Error Message:**

```
{
"timestamp": 1515127031483,
"status": 400,
"error": "Bad Request",
"exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
"message": "Could not read document: Cannot construct instance of `com.api.service.request.CreateUserRequest`, problem: email\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 6, column: 1]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.api.service.request.CreateUserRequest`, problem: email\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 6, column: 1]",
"path": "/create"
}
```

**API Input:**

```
curl -X PUT \
http://localhost:8080/create \
-H 'authorization: Basic Ymx1bWV3OjEyMw==' \
-H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
-H 'content-type: application/json' \
-d '{
    "CreateUserRequest" : {
        "email" : "--REDACTED--",
        "password" : "--REDACTED--"
    }
}'
```

**API Controller:**

```
@RestController
public class BaseActivity {

@RequestMapping(path = "/create", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public @ResponseBody String createUser (final @RequestBody CreateUserRequest createUserRequest) { ... }
```

**WebConfig:**

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.api.service"})
public class ActivityConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }

    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter 
        mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = new 
            MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper() 
        .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        jsonConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
        return jsonConverter;
    }
}
```

**Request Object:**

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CreateUserRequest implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4260711945094777831L;

    @NonNull
    private String email;

    @NonNull
    private String password;
}
```

*Note: When I replace the lombok annotations from the createUserRequest class, the API gets invoked but the email/password attributes are null.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your RequestBody is something like this

```
{
    "CreateUserRequest" : {
        "email" : "--REDACTED--",
        "password" : "--REDACTED--"
    }
}
```

But I think it should be like following:

```
{
  "email" : "--REDACTED--",
  "password" : "--REDACTED--"
}
```